# System.Timers.Timer delay hangs application

Tags: c#, timer

I have an issue with the System.Timers.Timer object. I use the timer object to perform a task at regular intervals. In the timer constructor I call the method doing the work ( DoTimeCheck() ), to ensure that the task is run once at startup also. The work (at regular intervals) is done in a BackgroundWorker.

I call the timer with this:

```
 UpdaterTimer ut = UpdaterTimer.UpdaterTimerInstance;
```

My problem is that I need to delay the first run of the task with 3 minutes(the one that runs at application startup). Subsequent runs (Elapsed event) should run without delay. I thought of doing this by calling

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeToDelayFirstRunInMiliseconds);
```

but this fails, because it also hangs the UI of the app (main thread) making it unusable. How can I delay the first run of DoTimeCheck() without hanging the UI? 
The code of the timer is below. If the issue is not presented in a clear manner please let me know and I will edit. Thank you in advance.

```
  public sealed class UpdaterTimer : Timer
{
    private static readonly UpdaterTimer _timer = new UpdaterTimer();
    public static UpdaterTimer UpdaterTimerInstance
    {
        get { return _timer; }
    }

    static UpdaterTimer()
    {
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Interval = Utils.TimeBetweenChecksInMiliseconds;
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start();
        DoTimeCheck();

    }

    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoTimeCheck();
    }

    private static void DoTimeCheck()
    {
        //... work here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the entire class?  (just curious about inheriting from Timer with all static methods)

Comment: thank you for your comment - that is the relevant entire class yes, apart from the code inside DoTimeCheck(). all the statics are supposed to ensure that only one timer is run - a singleton. Of course this may not be the best way of inheriting from System.Timers.Timer (i'm a newb), but it has worked so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to give the Timer Interval an initial value (e.g. 3 minutes). Then, in your Elapsed event handler, you could change the interval to your regular value which will be used from then on.

```
 _timer.Interval = Utils.InitialCheckInterval;

 static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (_timer.Interval == Utils.InitialCheckInterval)
     {
         _timer.Interval = Utils.RegularCheckInterval;
     }

     DoTimeCheck();
 }
```

Comment: Do you not want to swap Utils.TimeBetween... with Utils.RegularInterval?

Comment: Don't think so - the timer will be set to initial value. Then the first time the Interval Elapses it will be changed to the regular interval.

Comment: I think you edited it between my and your comment and I'm suspecting you only saw my comment after the edit. But yes, it looks good now. :)

Comment: @Chris I did - but I didn't swap them, just made the names clearer. Think we were both thinking the same anyway.

Comment: @Peter Kelly: Yeah, we're on the same page so all is good. At least it shows that making the names clearer was worthwhile. ;-)

Comment: @Chris exactly! There is so much value in well-named methods and variables.

Answer (score 1):

It appears (although you've not shown that code) that you're calling `Sleep(TimeToDelayFirstRunInMiliseconds);` on the main/GUI thread, so that's what's causing your UI thread to hang. Instead, you should set your timer to be delayed by 3 minutes on the first run, then once it runs you change the timer again to run at the frequency you desire for all the subsequent runs.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using timers fine it seems. Just use another one to do a three minute delay before you start up your other timer.

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.AutoReset = false;
timer.Interval = 3*60*1000;
timer.Elapsed += startOtherTimerMethod;
timer.Start();
```

**Edit:**  I should note that this is much the same as Peter Kelly's answer except that his solution is more elegant since it uses just one timer, no extra methods and takes advantage of the fact that the timer is changeable between runs. If you liked this answer, you'll love his. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your UI resides on the same thread, so when you put the thread to sleep, it will cause your UI to hang as well. You need to run the timer on a different thread.

Comment: thank you for your comment - I only use a BackgroundWorker to do the long work. Other than that, I stay away from multithreading because that is a thin ice for me, I do not have a good understanding of multithreading yet.

Comment: You're going to need it here. There are safe ways to do multithreading in .NET though, so don't be discouraged. Take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your UI needs a seperate thread, currently you are also sleeping the UI.  Check [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/34c37a0e-d457-4c6f-a01f-b7f10c9dd685/).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use thread.sleep in this situation you should use the winforms control

BackgroundWorker which never locks the main UI.  You can write your logic there.

example here:
http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/backgroundworker.html

Comment: thank you but i already use BackgroundWorker for the method that does all the work.  I have already tried adding the sleep method inside the BackgroundWorker but : 1 - hanging of UI still happens and 2 - this means that the delay will happen on each timer.Elapsed() event, and I need to delay only the first run.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) - the constructor takes a parameter for the delay of the first run and an interval for the subsequent runs.